# The primary key read from the row during the execution of the query was detected to be null. Primary keys must not contain null

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I use EclipseLink for JPA when I try to get data in my java application. when I Execute

```
 public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT t0.* FROM asset t0 WHERE t0.case_id = ?1  and t0.deleted=0 and t0.state='DEFAULT'  and fully_paid=0 and NOT EXISTS ( " +
                                                      " SELECT 1 from excluding_request er where er.asset_id=t0.ID and probable=0 and deleted = 0 and rejected = 0) order by t0.id limit ?2 , ?3", Asset.class);
            q.setParameter(1, caseId);
            q.setParameter(2, start);
            q.setParameter(3, limit);
            List<Asset> result = (List<Asset>) q.getResultList();
            return result;
        }
    });
```

I get no error, but almost the same query:

```
public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(t0.ID) FROM asset t0 WHERE t0.case_id = ?1  and t0.deleted=0 and t0.state='DEFAULT'  and fully_paid=0 and NOT EXISTS ( " +
                                                      " SELECT 1 from excluding_request er where er.asset_id=t0.ID and probable=0 and deleted = 0 and rejected = 0)", Asset.class);
            q.setParameter(1, caseId);
            Integer result = ((List<Integer>)q.getSingleResult()).get(0);
            return result;
        }
```

I get error:
**Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord(
         => 37931)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.**

It looks like some problem with count and eclipselink. By the way 37931 is result that should be returned in my case. Both queries work fine when I execute them directly in MySQL, and error is same no matter what I put in count function (*, 1, etc...)

Can you please tell me what an I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: One update. I tried uppercase letters, and also it didn't help here.